How to install revtex4-1.cls for my TeXworks (from revtex4-1.zip)?
I am using TexWorks to compile a .tex files and it throws " Please update your system to include revtex4-1.cls". I download revtex4-1.zip from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1 as suggested by this anwser.
However, how should I install revtex4-1.cls from this revtex4-1.zip? It is not a *.tar.lzma file so I can't install it by my MikTeX Console. I unzip the revtex4-1.zip and then what should I do?

I am using TexWorks/MikTeX on windows 11. Should I move the whole unzipped revtex4-1 to some directory?

Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as I know is there an updated version 4-2. I would use this one...

aastex631.cls ask me to include revtex4-1.cls so I have to use it and today is 2024-12-12. Neither do I know how to install revtex4-2. @Mensch

It seems not in miktex, otherwise it will not warn me to include revtex4-1. @DavidCarlisle

You should probably contact whoever is maintaining aastex631 and inform them that they should update  to revtex4-2 as revtex4-1 is not widely distributed anymore

And you can refer to this page: https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1?lang=en

@Harry ah sorry I didn't spot it was only in texlive, I deleted the comment
